# Alterar ação do icone voltar com fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com dificuldade em alterar a ação do ícone voltar <- na minha toolbar. Tenho dois fragments A e B sendo que B são detalhes de A. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 - Quando estou no fragment B e pressiono <- queria ir para o Fragment A. *Atualmente ele abre o Navigation Drawer.*

obs.: Pensei em reescrever o método onBackPressed() mas como estou em um fragment não é possível.

obs2.: Quando pressiono o botao físico voltar ele chama o fragment A pois abro o Fragment B utilizando utilizando empilhamento(código abaixo)

```
 ft.replace(R.id.main_content, mFrag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

Segue código da Activity principal e Manifest

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Fragment Iniciado com o app
    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_content, new NoticiaFragment());
    toolbar.setTitle("NOTICIAS");
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.about) {
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_content, new SobreFragment());
        ft.commit();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.noticias) {
        //TODO acessar toolbar pelo fragment para alterar o titulo
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_content, new NoticiaFragment());
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.sobre){
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_content, new SobreFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_48dp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para sobrescrever a ação do Up Navigation no fragment, você precisa fazer umas coisas:

Primeiro:

No `onCreateView` do fragment, declare este método:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true); // Informa ao Android que este fragment contém menu próprio
```

Após isso, nesse mesmo fragment, de `@Override` no método `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == android.R.id.home) { // Captura toques no Up Navigation
     // Faça a ação que você quiser
}
```

Feito isso, você pode fazer com que o Up Navigation tenha um comportamento
específico para o fragment em questão.

***EDIT:***

Dei uma olhada no código que você adicionou, tente adicionar esse método no `onCreate` da sua `MainActivity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Faça isso após ter setado a `Toolbar`.

Comment: Luiz fiz assim mas não deu certo ele continua abrindo o navigation drawer.

Comment: Edite sua pergunte então e poste o código da activity onde estão esses fragments e também o manifest

Comment: ok Luiz ja editei a pergunta.

Comment: Editei a resposta, tente fazer também o que botei no Edit para ver se o problema continua.

Comment: quando coloco esse código passo a ter <--  na activity principal e ainda assim quando vou para o fragment B ele tem o comportamento de abrir o navigation drawer. To pesquisando pilha de fragment e o navigation drawer da api padrão mas ainda sem êxito.

Comment: Isso é muito estranho, sendo que você permanece na mesma activity ao trocar de fragments e ainda esta setando um comportamento diferente para o Up Navigation. Se eu pensar em algo, atualizo aqui.

Comment: Vou utilizar uma outra activity para detalhar por enquanto é bem mais simples. ainda obrigado.